# inline less source map compiled from node code

Tags: css, node.js, less, source-maps

The project I'm working on is using code to run the less compiler.

I'm having trouble adding an inline source map to the compiled css from my less files.
From node we are running the following code:

```
var less = require('less'),
    options = {
        strictMath: true
    };

less.render(data, options, function(err, css) {
    callback(err, css);
});
```

Is there an option I can add?
I've tried adding `sourceMap: true` and `outputSourceFiles: true` without success.

Comment: You may want to double check your LESS version, LESS.js only supports source maps as of 1.5

Answer (score 0):

Since Less v 1.5 the compiler has support for the following options

```
  --source-map[=FILENAME]  Outputs a v3 sourcemap to the filename (or output filename.map)
  --source-map-rootpath=X  adds this path onto the sourcemap filename and less file paths
  --source-map-basepath=X  Sets sourcemap base path, defaults to current working directory.
  --source-map-less-inline puts the less files into the map instead of referencing them
  --source-map-map-inline  puts the map (and any less files) into the output css file
  --source-map-url=URL     the complete url and filename put in the less file
```

The `sourceMap` and `outputSourceFiles` options you have tried seems to related to grunt-contrib-less, see: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less